# Angularjs directive testing - it seems compilation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, coffeescript, jasmine

I'm trying to test my Angular directive with no success...

```
describe 'mylist directive', () ->

    beforeEach module 'myModule'

    beforeEach module 'my-tpl'

    beforeEach inject (_$httpBackend_, _$templateCache_) ->
        @$httpBackend = _$httpBackend_
        @$templateCache = _$templateCache_

    it 'Replaces the element with the appropriate content', () ->
        inject ($compile, $rootScope) ->
            rootScope = $rootScope.$new()
            @$httpBackend.when('GET', 'list.html').respond @$templateCache.get 'list.html'
            element = $compile('<mylist ng-model="items" title="Test"></mylist>')(rootScope)
            rootScope.$digest()
            console.log element
            expect(element.html()).toContain "sometext"
```

for some reason, console.log() prints the original content instead of compiled one:

```
Object{0: <mylist ng-model="items" title="Test" class="ng-scope"></mylist>, length: 1}
```

(*@$templateCache.get 'list.html'* returns correct template - I've checked)

any advice would be helpful....

Comment: Are you sure there is a `mylist` directive ? Try `rootScope.$apply()` instead of `rootScope.$digest()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. mylist is defined inside myModule. I was trying rootScope.$apply() - it doesn't help